# Books to accompany Hartshorne's first chapter

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-geometry

I'm studying the first chapter of Hartshorne's *Algebraic Geometry* by myself and I found this book really hard for a beginner like me, but my advisor said to me that I had to study Algebraic Geometry by this book during my vacations. Then any part of the Hartshorne's book which I find very dry or superficial I search the same subject in another books or notes available online which are easier to read and have more examples.

So my question is if there is some book or pdf to accompany Hartshorne's book? I mean the same contents but more detailed, if there isn't such book, it can be a book for each section of the first chapter. In this way, the first chapter of Hartshorne's book for me would be more a route to follow for an introduction of algebraic geometry, than a book to study.

**Remark**: I know there are a lot of posts asking requests of books in algebraic geometry on this site, my question is more specific, I'm only asking this because I couldn't find any good resources with I need.

Any suggestions would be really appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You might also want to see these answers:
http://mathoverflow.net/questions/14371/looking-for-an-introductory-textbook-on-algebraic-geometry-for-an-undergraduate
http://mathoverflow.net/questions/2446/best-algebraic-geometry-text-book-other-than-hartshorne/

Comment: Why a book to accompany Hartshorne's book? Just replace it! Many suggestions were already given in the linked MO discussions.

Answer (score 10):

There are many books which help pave the way for and/or supplement for Hartshorne. I like, in particular, [Basic Algebraic Geometry, Volume 1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3540548122)  by Shafarevich.

A handy and readily available guide is [Milne's lecture notes](http://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/ag.html), which you can legally download ("for free") from the Internet.

Perhaps the most elementary introduction to algebraic geometry is Miles Reid's *Undergraduate Algebraic Geometry*.  The first three chapters are available [here](http://www.uam.es/personal_pdi/ciencias/abenito/varios/ReidAlgebraicGeometry.pdf).

Comment: Isn't *Shafarevich's* elementary? I don't know. I bought and planned to learn in some time.

Comment: Yes, indeeed, @FrankScience

Comment: @amWhy: Nice suggestions +1

Comment: @amWhy I agree with Amzoti so $\huge\color{blue}{+}$

Answer (score 6):

The best algebraic geometry notes I've seen are definitely Andreas Gahtmann notes. They are freely available at his [website](http://www.mathematik.uni-kl.de/~gathmann/alggeom.php?lang=en).

Answer (score 1):

I think [Ravi Vakil's notes](http://math.stanford.edu/~vakil/216blog/) are perfect as a very readable alternative to Hartshorne, covering more or less the same material if I recall correctly.

Comment: These notes build in the scheme language/machinery from the get-go. They are extremely nice for one who wants to learn schemes, but this is not what is covered in the first chapter of Hartshorne.